# Python: getting finding a variable in a string

Tags: python, string, url, variables, urllib

I currently have some code that goes to a URL, fetches the source code, and I'm trying to get it to return a variable from the string. So I created:

changetime = refreshsource.find('VARIABLE pm NST')

But it wouldn't find the area in the string because the word is not VARIABLE, it is something else. How would I retrieve the constantly changing VARIABLE from that string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) will be able to achieve this for you. I'd you give some examples of what variable will be the we could come up with a strict expression. To match what you have above something like the following will do:

```
import re
# this will match 01:23, 11:34, 12:00, etc.
timex = re.compile('.*(\d{2}:\d{2})[ ]?pm NST')
match = timex.match(text, re.M|re.S)
variable = match.groups(0)
```

**Edit:** this code will actually work (unlike that first attempt :) ):

```
import re
# this will match 01:23, 11:34, 12:00, etc.
timex = re.compile('(\d{2}:\d{2})[ ]?pm NST')

match = timex.search(text)
if match:
    variable = match.groups(0)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about regular expressions, I'll try it out!

Comment: I think there might be a small bug in that example:
`text = "\n10:15pm NST" # would not match`
I suggest this:
`timex = re.compile(r'([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})pm NST')
timex.search(text)`

Comment: Also there might be a space between time and pm, like `10:15 pm`. The regex doesn't handle that.

Comment: `timex = re.compile(r'([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}) ?pm NST')`

Comment: I was looking at it on mobile and wasn't sure if there was a space there or not. I've modified the code to reflect that.

Comment: Only saw your comment now @Justin. You're right. I wrote this on my phone and didn't test it.

Comment: @JohnKeyes - Oh but I still applaud you for remembering the various flags from the "re" module, while typing an answer from your phone!

Comment: @Justin Hahaha you're much too kind.

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern is really that simple, then this seems a typical case where [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) comes quite handy.
Note: if you are new to regular expressions, you may want to use some introduction, like the http://www.regular-expressions.info.

On the other hand, if the pattern is more complex, then you may want to use an HTML parser, like for instance [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: Thanks, It's simple so I'll check out regular expressions.